# Explainable AI (XAI) : Permutation Importance

Tags: xai, eli5

I was using the model `Permutation Importance` for checking the Explainability (XAI) of my ML model. The XAI model i.e., `Permutation Importance` is supposed to show the **Weights** against all the **Features** of the dataset. Now the problem is, the XAL model is not showing all the feature names in the output. And I need the output with all the features.

Can anyone kindly help me to show the output with the names of all the features? I have used the following code:

```
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

perm = PermutationImportance(rfc, random_state=1).fit(X_test, Y_test)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X_train.columns.tolist())
```

I tried searching for the solution where I can mention the number of features specifically. But didn't find any answer.